App crashes on android 14 devices after mandatory update to targetSdkVersion to version 34 in React Native
After upgrading targetSdkVersion to version 34 and publishing a new version of my app in the Google Play Store, I receive an email from google stating that:
Your app still uses a version of the Play Core library that is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34, listed here:
- com.google.android.play:core

After reading up on the subject and following the steps in this reply on the same subject StackOverFlow Answer, I couldn't find any dependencies on my installed libraries in my dependencies.txt. Nowhere in my project did I find anything related to com.google.android.play:core. The closest I found to dependencies was com.google.android.gms:play.
Can anyone suggest anything about this? Could my Android 14 problem be related to com.google.android.gms:play?
First of all thank you for wasting your time trying to help me.

Google does not publish an artifact named com.google.android.gms:play, though that is the prefix for many artifacts.
